# Changing a line in a text file if it exists

Tags: linux, bash, replace, sed, line

I know you can change a line in a text file using sed in bash that shows something like;

name="applicationname" //this is not the issue (it varies, thats why i use a var)

Depiction: http://google.com 
or 
Depiction: http://yahoo.com //some times the 'value' in depiction varies

to

Depiction: http://mysite.com/depiction.php?package=applicationname //this is the format i would like to achieve

by using sed, but I'm not entirely sure how to implement sed.
http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/

EDIT: This is what i just came up with

```
sed -i "s!Depiction:.*!Depiction: http://mysite.com/depiction.php?package=$name!" ./inputfile
```

What if in this particular text file, there isnt a 'Depiction:'?
how do i insert a line: Depiction: http://mysite.com/depiction.php?package=applicationname ?

Comment: I've solved my problem, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to come up with the answer with many trials and errors... so just to share. :)

```
if grep -Fq "Depiction:" ./file
then
sed -i "s!Depiction:.*!Depiction: http://mysite.com/depiction.php?package=$name" ./file
else
sed -i 1i"Depiction: http://mysite.com/depiction.php?package=$name" ./file
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try it this way: remove all instances of "Depiction:" then append the line you want

```
{
  grep -v "Depiction:" filename
  echo "Depiction: ..."
} > newfile && mv newfile filename
```

Comment: As I said in my answer, "Delete it, then add, *if you don't care about the order*". This will change the position of the line if it existed and put it at the bottom. Good solution, if you don't care about that.

Answer (score 0):

sed is most valuable for simple substitutions. Once you have logic like "if not found, do X", you should move to a more general-purpose language. I like [Python](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html):

```
from sys import argv, stdout

filename = argv[1]
depiction_found = False
for line in open(filename):
    line.replace('foo', 'bar') #I'm not too sure what you're really trying to do
    if line.startswith("Depiction: "):
        depiction_found = True
    stdout.write(line)

if not depiction_found:
    stdout.write("Depiction: <correct value here>\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete it, then add, if you don't care about the order. Or use awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{replacement="Depiction: http://mysite.com/depiction.php?package=applicationname"}/^Depiction:/{print replacement;found=1}!/^Depiction:/{print}END{if(!found)print replacement}' < file
```

or any other higher-order language.

Comment: awk is the path to the dark side. awk leads to perl. perl leads to suffering.

Comment: @bukzor: Seriously? I'll use Ruby where you'd use Python; but this is a one-liner, and exactly what awk is good at.

Comment: `sed 's/Depiction:\ .*/Depiction:\ http://mysite.com/depiction?package=$name/'`
will this work?

Comment: @AlwynIsPat: Only if it exists; which is the reason OP came here with this question in the first place.

Comment: `sed -i "s!Depiction:.*!Depiction: http://mysite.com/depiction.php?package=$name!" ./inputfile`
this works...

i'll i need now is to check if the word "Depiction" exists...

Comment: @Amadan: I'm mostly kidding, but I wouldn't suggest learning awk to anyone that doesn't already know it.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed -i '/Depiction:.*/{h;s||Depiction: http://mysite.com/depiction.php?package='"$name"'|};$!b;x;/./{x;q};x;a\Depiction: http://mysite.com/depiction.php?package='"$name" ./inputfile
```

or perhaps as the barebones:

```
sed -i '/foo/{h;s//FOO/};$!b;x;/./{x;q};x;a\FOO' file
```

In essence:

- If `foo` exists, make a copy in the hold space (HS) and carry out substitution.
- At end of file (`$`) check the hold space for evidence or previous substitution and if none append a line.